# Why is my AWS NLB forwarding traffic to a single ec2 instance in my target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, nlb

Using cloud formation I setup an autoscaling group (2x Ec2 instances), a target group and a network load balancer in front of it that forwards traffic. I have a few iot devices (20) that are connecting to a service running on the ec2 instances on port 443. All tcp connections are routed to only one of the ec2 instances instead of being distributed to both.

I have read about the algorithm that the network load balancer uses so I ran a couple of the devices on my local network and some in Spain in order to make sure the source ip, port, location are different. All connection went to the same ec2 instance.

Expected result: connections to both ec2 instances.
Actual result: all connections are forwarded to the same ec2 instance.

Comment: could you include some or all of the template you used?

Comment: go to console and check the targroup group does it container proper or expected instance in the target

Comment: everything seems to be ok from a setup point of view and I just discovered that if I restart all devices at the same time some of the connections do get forwarded to the secondary ec2 instance. For simplicity I will use A and B for the 2 ec2 instances. If I restart the iot devices one by one all connections go to A. If I restart all iot devices at the same time some connections go to A and some to B. I'm trying to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

I will mark this as closed since the connections do get routed to different instances when more requests come at the same time as mentioned in my comment.